Python Dataframe Find Strings and Change Their Values
I have a dataframe includes 15 columns. Data mining process is ongoing. degree_type column has lower and uppercase letters, punctuation and abbreviation. I want to find all Bachelor's Degrees (in the dataset there aren't only 15 rows, thousands rows I have)  and change their values with "Bachelor's Degree".
ID: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15 should be changed. How can I write this code in Python?



ID
degree_type




1
BACHELOR'S DEGREE


2
Bachelor of Science


3
Bachelors


4
BEng


5
Bachelor of Engineering


6
Bachelor of Applied Science


7
Engineer’s Degree


8
Computer Engineering


9
Certification


10
Bachelor of Technology (B.Tech.)


11
(M.B.A.)


12
BA.


13
BS.


14
B.A.Sc


15
(B.A.)



